# How to find dynamic sub foldername in my Local file path using regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find dynamic sub foldername in my Local file path using regular expression.For example File path is

> E:\Current Project\Regex
>   Samples\trunk\TestApplication\Uploads\Dynamicfolder123\EncryptedFile\

I want to get sub foldername  `Dynamicfolder123`

my code:

```
string strvalue=@"E:\Current Project\Regex Samples\trunk\TestApplication\Uploads\Dynamicfolder123\EncryptedFile\";
Match oMatch =Regex.Match(strvalue,@"^Uploads\(.*?)\EncryptedFile\",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 if (oMatch.Success)
   {
    MessageBox.Show(oMatch.Value);
   }
```

Comment: If the question is "why isn't the match a success", I think it's because of the `^` in  `@"^Uploads` etc. - this means it will only match at the start of the input string, and `Uploads` isn't at the start.

Comment: You could `System.IO.Directory.GetParent(strvalue).Parent.Name` which has the advantage of raising appropriate exceptions should the need arise

Answer (score 0):

I am amazed no one answered this.

```
string path = @"E:\Current Project\Regex Samples\trunk\TestApplication\Uploads\Dynamicfolder123\EncryptedFile\";

string pattern =@"
(?:Uploads\\)       # Match but don't capture Uploads\
(?<Dynamic>[^\\]+)  # Extract directory into named capture Dynamic
";

// IgnoreWhitespace allows us to comment the pattern, does not affect regex processing.
Console.WriteLine ( Regex.Match(path, 
                                pattern, 
                                RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
                         .Groups["Dynamic"].Value);

/* Output
Dynamicfolder123
*/
```